# Pass Parameter to ViewScoped Bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans

I'm going to pass a parameter from one page (Facelet) to a Managed Bean whose scope is View Scope.

I try to do it like this:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Mybean {
  private int id;


  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }    
}
```

First page:

```
  <h:body>            
    <h:form>
      <h:commandLink value="click" action="index">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{mybean.id}" value="20"/>
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
```

second page:

```
  <h:body>
    param value #{param.id}
    <br />
    bean value #{mybean.id}
    <br />

    <h:messages/>
  </h:body>
```

**But it does not show 20**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ViewScoped` bean stays only for the view that the user is watching.

Once the user switched to another view - the bean is being destroyed and created from scratch. 
Therefore, if you want to use the same bean for more than one page - use `@SessionScoped` bean.

Another way, is to create a `Singleton` class in Java, and one bean will update the value in this class, while the other bean will extract the value from it.

Comment: You are right, and I can change it to RequestScope too, right?

Comment: The singleton class will keep the values like an ApplicationScoped bean! I mean the value will be the same for all visitors, won't be?

Comment: You are right! so you can use session scope bean to store the values if it's for many users