# Pass parameter to bean associated with PrimeFaces Dialog Frameworks' dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, parameter-passing, dialog-framework

I have a template with button which opens dialog:

```
<p:commandButton 
      id="roles-button" 
      icon="fa fa-key">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user}" target="#{userAdministrationView.selectedUser}" />
      <f:actionListener binding="#{userAdministrationView.openUserRolesDialogWithParameters()}"/>
          <p:ajax 
               event="dialogReturn" 
               listener="#{dialogHandler.showMessage}"
               update=":user-administration-form:user-administration-table" 
               global="false"
          />
</p:commandButton>
```

Backing bean for template (userAdministrationView) is @ViewScoped.

I want to pass parameter `selectedUser` to the dialog. Is it possible with using Faces.setContext/Request/FlashAttribute, like adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694423/pass-an-object-between-viewscoped-beans-without-using-get-params)? I tried to implement it like:

```
public void openUserRolesDialogWithParameters() {
    Faces.setContextAttribute("user", selectedUser);
    dialogHandler.openDialog("user-roles-dialog");
}
```

and in dialogs backing bean (which is @ViewScoped too):

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.user = Faces.getContextAttribute("user");
    ...
}
```

but I get `null` in `user`. The same result is with setRequestAttribute and setFlashAttribute.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583968/pass-parameter-to-viewscoped-bean) it is suggested to create @SessionScoped bean with properties, but this decision looks not very relevant for me. Is it the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), i started to search in right direction, and I found [this explanation](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40250). 
So, it works like this:

template backing bean :

```
public void openUserRolesDialogWithParameters() {
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    sessionMap.put("user", selectedUser);
    dialogHandler.openDialog("user-roles-dialog", "contentWidth", "500");
}
```

dialog backing bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    this.user = (UserModel) sessionMap.get("user");
    sessionMap.remove("user");
    ...
}
```